# SQL Create View displaying items sold Today

Tags: sql, view

I am busy with my SQL Final exam preparation

My question is this, I have to create a View to display products bought Today and I must display the product name and price and customer name

my code is

```
USE pre_prac 
GO

CREATE VIEW vw_Today
AS
SELECT Customer.custName, Product.prodName, Product.prodPrice, Invoice.invDate 
FROM Customer 
JOIN Product 
ON Customer.custName = Product.prodIden  
JOIN Invoice 
ON Product.prodName = Invoice.invDate  
WHERE Invoice.invDate = GETDATE()
GO
```

Is my code wrong or what am I missing

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Some product specific functionality there.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need proper join with the corresponding table column(i mean relation with customer table to others table). it would be easy to submit write code if you provide your table schema. so far from my understanding below code may be your helpful

```
USE pre_prac 
GO

CREATE VIEW vw_Today
AS
SELECT Customer.custName, Product.prodName, Product.prodPrice, Invoice.invDate 
FROM Customer 
JOIN Product 
ON Customer.prodIden = Product.prodIden 
JOIN Invoice 
ON Product.invoiceId = Invoice.invoiceId  
WHERE Invoice.invDate = GETDATE()
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `JOIN` How can `Customer.custName = Product.prodIden` and `Product.prodName = Invoice.invDate`
This is the error, you should have a relation based on an `Integer` column, for example Table `Product` should contain a `FK` from table `Customer` called `CustomerId` , etc!